# Python Class in Class

Tags: python, class

Someone can help me to correct this error ? thanks
(I'm trying to access a variable in the mother class in the daughter class)

```py
class Animal:
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    class Mammal:
        
        def Presentation(self):
            print(self.name + "is a mammal")
            
dog = Animal("Dog")
dog.Mammal.Presentation()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 11, in 
TypeError: Presentation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self1'

Comment: What do you mean by "mother" and "daughter" class? You declared a nested class, but you have neither an instance nor any direct reference to the enclosing class you could use

Comment: Why do you think `Mammal` objects will have a  `self.name` attribute? it isn't assigned *anywhere*? What do you believe nesting a class definition inside another class definition does? It *does not* create an inheritance relationship. In fact, it doesn't really do anything useful at all, except perhaps keep namespaces seperate

Comment: "I'm trying to access a variable in the mother class in the daughter class" But you have *no reference to any instance of the Animal class*, and again, there is **no** mother/daughter relationship here. Your error occurs because you try to call the method on the class object, not on an instance, but then there is no `self`, hence the error.

Comment: A mammal isn't an attribute of an animal; it's a *kind* of animal.

Answer (score 3):

Not the actual answer to your question, but I guess you want to do something like this:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def Presentation(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Mammal(Animal):
    def Presentation(self):
        print(self.name + "is a mammal")


dog = Mammal("Dog")
dog.Presentation()
```

Comment: You don't need to define `Mammal.__init__`, since it just calls the same method that the expression `Mammal.__init__` would resolve to if it weren't defined.

Comment: yes thats true, my first unedited answer didn't containt the __init__ function. But I wanted to show how one calls it, in case of changing the parameter "name"

Comment: @ExceptionFinder overriding `__init__` is not showing anything useful here. The whole *point* of inheritance is code re-use.

Comment: @ExceptionFinder Then at the very least, change the name of the parameter, or do something that warrants overriding the method. As it is now, it's just noise.

Comment: @chepner Fine, I removed it :) Although that's not my personal prefrence.

Comment: @ExceptionFinder why is it your preference? It *doesn't do anything* and is only confusing to people used to reading normal code.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because in my opiniton it is bad practice, Sure in this case it's obvious that the base class member variable will be instantiated, but a lazy programmer might add a new construtcor without calling it's baseclass'. A lot of stuff can happen and when it's possible to avoid a lot of prolems by adding "noisy" code, I will do that.

Answer (score -1):

The child class would have to inherit the parent self attribute to do that.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    class Mammal:
        def Presentation(inherit):
            print(inherit.name + “is a mammal”)
dog = Animal("Dog")
Animal.Mammal.Presentation(dog)
```

Comment: well, this is *a* solution, but it isn't inheritance, there is no parent/child class here. This is simply providing an argument to a method. And incorrectly using classes

Comment: @AbrarAhmed right, it would have to be `Animal.Mammal.Presentation(dog)` to not throw an error, regardless, it would still not be the correct way of doing this

Comment: I would be sincerely interested in seeing the correct way of doing this for a project I am working on.

Comment: @JacobLee correct way of doing *what*? Using inheritance? Fundamentally, there is no need for nesting classes. That does nothing useful. You inherit from another class by using dosmething like `class Child(Parent): ...` in the class definition.

Comment: Okay, so it just is impractical.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to, nesting classes? Yes, that is usually just impractical. Other languages like Java have so-called "inner classes", i.e. non-static nested classes that do behave differently from how nested classes work in Python (in Python, they work like Java static nested classes). There's rarely a good use-case, sometimes it makes sense for code organization purposes.

Comment: `Animal.Mammal.Presentation(dog)` is also just fundamentally confused. `Presentation` is written as an *instance* method, but you aren't calling it as such. Note, `self` isn't attribute, and that is certainly not inheriting it.